# Openstack - Controller node

Tags: cloud, openstack

How to assign ns to my network interfaces?

I have followed the following steps :

1. ip netns

after executing the above command i could not get any ns assignment details.

1. pgrep -fl dnsmasq
   after executing this command i have got the following details

1548 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -u libvirt-dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/libvirt/network/default.pid --conf-file= --except-interface lo --listen-address 192.168.122.1 --dhcp-range 192.168.122.2,192.168.122.254 --dhcp-leasefile=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.leases --dhcp-lease-max=253 --dhcp-no-override
4423 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --conf-file= --pid-file=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.pid --listen-address=10.4.128.3 --except-interface=lo --dhcp-range=set:private,10.4.128.2,static,255.255.240.0,120s --dhcp-lease-max=4096 --dhcp-hostsfile=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.conf --dhcp-script=/usr/local/bin/nova-dhcpbridge --leasefile-ro --domain=novalocal --no-hosts --addn-hosts=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.hosts
4424 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --strict-order --bind-interfaces --conf-file= --pid-file=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.pid --listen-address=10.4.128.3 --except-interface=lo --dhcp-range=set:private,10.4.128.2,static,255.255.240.0,120s --dhcp-lease-max=4096 --dhcp-hostsfile=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.conf --dhcp-script=/usr/local/bin/nova-dhcpbridge --leasefile-ro --domain=novalocal --no-hosts --addn-hosts=/opt/stack/data/nova/networks/nova-br100.hosts

with this details how to set the namespace(ns)?

Answer (score 0):

In openstack network namespaces are used allow tenants to use same network id. They are created for you when you have atleast one network in openstack.

Can you tell me what exactly you are trying.